# Add connection drivers SQLSERVER (ODBC, sqlsrv.dll) in CPANEL

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, cpanel

good afternoon, I have a project that was developed in codeigniter and sqlserver, locally it is working perfectly, but now that I uploaded it to cpanel it is showing me a connection error DB and I imagine it is because of the drivers that are needed. My doubt is, How can I activate or add the drivers to CPANEL?

> Files you use locally:

1. extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_ts.dll,
2. extension=php_sqlsrv_74_ts.dll
3. Install the ODBC

> ERROR

***Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()***

I hope you can support me.

Comment: are you maintaining the production server yourself? if not you should contact the service provider.

Comment: Hire a service WHM (Web Host Manager), that I have to do?

Comment: well depends, but if you hired a server, the company you hired from should provide customer service, if it is your own server maintained by yourself, you need to make the same settings which made the whole thing working locally. The database settings for local and production might be different and are set in application/config/database.php

Comment: These were the links to check when installing the drivers locally, Do I have to put the lines of code that the documentation indicates in the console?

Comment: SQLSRV: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: OBDC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15